# Wordpress Deadlock found - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been experiencing the below errors. For some reason i guess the it reaches it's time limit and it explodes..

Site is really slow (contains about 2.5k posts).
Other sites with the same amount of posts are going just fine.
404 on some cases when trying to add new post.

Below is some lines of my error_log

```
[18-May-2014 07:36:22 UTC] Î£Ï†Î¬Î»Î¼Î± Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction Î²Î¬ÏƒÎ·Ï‚ Î´ÎµÎ´Î¿Î¼Î­Î½Ï‰Î½ WordPress Î³Î¹Î± Î±Î¯Ï„Î·ÏƒÎ· DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_transient_doing_cron' Î±Ï€ÏŒ require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), call_user_func_array, wp_cron, spawn_cron, get_transient, delete_option
```

Right after that it loses the connection to the Database and i get `Mysql server has gone away`

I could `$this->query("set session wait_timeout=600");` but it still on some cases crashes.

Any idea what might be trying to `DELETE` from the wp_options table ?
I kind of concerned on the `DELETE` part too be honest too

Comment: Hi Teris, did you solve this issue?

Comment: Afraid not sorry. Did you have the same thing ?

Comment: Yes I did. I can't find a solution!